# High pitch voices(female screams) hurt testicles

Tags: testosterone, testicles

Female would scream(or high pitched male) would scream at me my testicles would contract and hurt.  After gaining a lot of weight my testosterone levels have dropped and I no longer have this issue(I'm only guessing).

I'm not sure if this is medical term/disorder for this or I have a genetic condition but I figured I should ask.  Does this have a medical term?

This issue could be alleviated by me putting an ear plug in my left ear(I'm not joking).

Comment: Does your anal sphincter also close?

Comment: @GrahamChiu I'm honestly not sure.  When girls would scream at me I would just leave and go somewhere else.  I would literally just stand up and leave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question.

It sounds like testicular pain like that could be due to contraction of the [cremaster muscle](https://www.healthline.com/human-body-maps/cremaster-muscle#1), which essentially controls testicle height. Its main role is to help regulate temperature in the scrotum by controlling how close the testicles are to the body. This is important because a very precise temperature is needed to make sperm (just a little colder than core body temperature).

I couldn't find anything to suggest that high-pitched sounds cause the cremaster to contract. However, there is some evidence to suggest that activation of the sympathetic nervous system (the "fight or flight" response) can cause the cremaster to contract.

In [this study](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/neuroscience/cremaster-muscle) the authors state that there is a

> reduction of myogenic responsiveness secondary to the elimination of
>   sympathetic activity.

In other words once the "fight or flight" response was disabled in these rats, the cremaster had less of a response. This indicates that the cremaster responds at least in part to the sympathetic nervous system.

My suspicion is that testicular pain in a situation like you described is due to contraction of the cremaster muscle. This was most likely caused by a sympathetic "fight or flight" response caused by the screaming/ confrontation. I don't know of any mechanism directly linking high-pitched sounds to the testicles.

Comment: That's my thought as well and the cremasteric contraction is listed on some sites as part of the flight response. Interestingly his response is flight as per comments. Habituation might be why it's no longer happening.

Comment: Yeah that was my thought as well re: habituation. Interesting stuff